# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error during init of libtorrent::session

Tags: c++, session, exc-bad-access, libtorrent

This is how I'm initializing my 'libtorrent::session ses' variable:

```
ses( fingerprint( "UT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, 8, 7, 0 )
                   , std::make_pair( 49152, 65534 )
                   , "0.0.0.0"
                   , session::add_default_plugins
                   , alert::progress_notification

                  )
```

However, I receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 during the execution of this line in the session constructor:

```
init(listen_port_range, listen_interface, print, alert_mask);
```

Here is the full source for the init method for reference, the line that is giving the error can be found in the following snippet:

```
            session(fingerprint const& print
            , std::pair<int, int> listen_port_range
            , char const* listen_interface = "0.0.0.0"
            , int flags = start_default_features | add_default_plugins
            , int alert_mask = alert::error_notification
            TORRENT_LOGPATH_ARG_DEFAULT)
        {
            TORRENT_CFG();
            TORRENT_ASSERT(listen_port_range.first > 0);
            TORRENT_ASSERT(listen_port_range.first < listen_port_range.second);
            init(listen_port_range, listen_interface, print, alert_mask);
   #if defined TORRENT_VERBOSE_LOGGING || defined TORRENT_LOGGING || defined TORRENT_ERROR_LOGGING
            set_log_path(logpath);
#endif
            start(flags);
        }
```

I've read that the culprit might be a zombie, i.e. a variable that has been released, however, I'm not sure which of those variables that I'm passing in during the init could've been released, they all seem fine to me.

The question is, why am I receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error during the initialization of my libtorrent::session variable?

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of libtorrent are you using? The error you post suggests you're on Mac OSX, is that right? How did you build libtorrent and how are you building your client?

Comment: I'm using the version of libtorrent in this repo: https://github.com/joedemo42/popcorntime-ios, the aforementioned repo is the one I'm trying to build. Yes, correct I'm on a Mac OSX. I didn't build libtorrent myself, I used the libtor.a built library that was included in the repo and I'm using Xcode to build the client found in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any ABI compatibility issues. libtorrent has a lot of build options that affect its ABI.

If you're building libtorrent as a shared library, make sure that all the TORRENT_* defines used to build libtorrent are also provided to the program including libtorrent headers.

This problem has been significantly reduced in libtorrent 1.0.x, in that version only these defines affect the ABI:

- TORRENT_USE_IPV6
- TORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE

In earlier versions these defines also affect the ABI:

- TORRENT_DEBUG
- TORRENT_DISABLE_DHT
- TORRENT_VERBOSE_LOGGING
- TORRENT_LOGGING
- TORRENT_DISABLE_RESOLVE_COUNTRIES
- TORRENT_DISABLE_FULL_STATS
- TORRENT_DISABLE_EXTENSIONS
- _UNICODE
- TORRENT_DISABLE_POOL_ALLOCATORS

However, abi issues are supposed to be detected by a missing symbol whose name include all configuration options. (see build_config.hpp for details).